# What is the Max Thread.Sleep Time?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Can anyone tell me the Max sleep time in ms for `Thread.sleep(time);` for use in Android OS ?

Comment: Considering that it takes a long parameter, the answer should be 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: @AmitBhargava That's the theoretical answer.

Comment: Why has this question got the android tag?... I think you need to elaborate on this question as well!

Comment: @Andy I should have specified. This is for Android OS, I realise the max for a long, but I wondered if the OS had different restrictions on Thread.Sleep time.

Comment: I'm curious why you think you need to know. Even if it's only Integer.MAX_VALUE it is still 24.85513480324074 days. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @EJP I have a application thread that sleeps for 20 minutes and then actions an event, but it only works for short sleeps under 60000 ms, anything over and it wont work. I thought there might be some android OS limit that restricts this. I guess It is my code that is the problem. I will re write with timer task or alarm manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no maximum time for `Thread.sleep()`. Whatever time you enter, for that time the thread sleeps.

Comment: That's what I was led to believe too, but I am currently writing an application that has an extended sleep time and it's playing up.

Comment: This is self-evidently false. The parameter has a maximum value dictated by the representation and semantics of the datatype.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it as Thread.sleep() limitation but rather language limitation. My point is that you won't even pass such high values that it wouldn't be capable of processing. It either does the job or you will lose data BEFORE this function is called and it will receive trimmed data.